# Building Maven Plugin - API to resolve maven properties

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3

I am creating a plugin that reads information from the pom and I'm encountering some properties such as ${basedir} etc when it comes to the elements that specifies directories. I was wondering if Maven have a API that I can use where I can just pass on that properties and they can resolve it for me.

preferably not having to run another plugin first. Its possible to do the crude way but was just wondering if there's anything "fancier" that i could use.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property which maven will inject the MavenProject model into:

/** @parameter default-value="${project}" */
private org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject mavenProject;

Then you can access properties via getProperties() as described here:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook#MojoDeveloperCookbook-StoringProperties

You'll also need to declare a dependency on org.apache.maven:maven-project:${version of maven} in your mojo's POM.

I hope that was what you were asking about...
-tim

Comment: Does that get the properties that are already pre-defined in Maven like ${basedir}?

Comment: It returns the properties defined in the POM's <properties> element.  When I printed the value of a config parameter annotated with expression=${basedir}, it was resolved to the actual base directory.  I guess I'm not understanding what you're asking.

Comment: When I put a variable in a <properties> element, it was resolved when I fetched it.

Comment: I see. What I was wondering is those properties that are default in Maven like ${basedir} etc, not those defined by <properties>. But nevertheless, I didn't know maven can resolve properties in <properties> for you so thats something new to me. Thanks

Comment: I think, but am not 100% sure, that all variables that can be resolved will be resolved by the time your plugin runs.